# How to enable code folding in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Running Jupyter**Lab** version 3.0.0 and would like to enable **code folding** (collapse classes, functions etc in Python). I have followed the instructions in this [Jupyter Lab github post](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4083#issuecomment-481453048):

Under Settings / Text Editor, I have these User preferences (right pane):

```
{
    "editorConfig": {
        "lineNumbers": true,
        "codeFolding": true
    }
}
```

And I do not see any triangles appearing on the left side of the cells. What else do I need to do in order to enable code folding?

For abundance of clarity, this question pertains to **JupyterLab** specifically.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Those instructions are specifically for the *[text editor](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/file_editor.html)*, not the notebook interface.

Try this instead, in Settings / Notebook:

```json
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "codeFolding": true
    }
}
```

If you want to enable code folding for Markdown or raw cells, see `markdownCellConfig` and `rawCellConfig` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Chris' answer, I enabled code folding in Lab by going to menu:

> Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor -> Cell Toolbar -> Notebook -> Rulers -> Checked box for "CodeFolding".

I'm using Labs 3.5.0.