# How to automatically fold code in Jupyter Lab editor?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Am using JupyterLab code editor (not the notebook)
and have a very long file and would like to automatically fold the code
using a Macro or at Start Up.

Comment: This thread might be helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532002/how-to-enable-code-folding-in-jupyter-lab